# C# prevent excel file from getting modified

Tags: c#, .net, excel, security

Hi I'm searching a way to **prevent** an **excel file** from being **modified**.
I **don't want to use hidden fields**, where you have to place a calculated hashcode in.

My program should be able to note that a file has been modified outside the application when I reopen the file.

**EDIT: Sorry i forgot to mention I also don't want to use a password**, because the excel file may be only edited in the application and not outside...

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect the excel file with a password : http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/the-password-you-can-always-remember/

Or can set restrictions only for editing with password protection: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/make-a-document-read-only-HA010152719.aspx

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention I also don't want to use a password

Comment: @daageu Then how would you want to obtain this functionality? It's security after all. You can either hide the file, use built in features like password protection, or maybe serialize it as a byte[] and encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Your restrictions are preventing the most sane methods, so I would do the following:
calculate a hash of the excel-file and save it somewhere.
When reopened, recalculate the hash and compare it with the old value...